# What is the derivative of $x \cdot (y^2+x^2)^{\frac{-1}{2}} \cdot t$ with respect to t

Tags: derivatives

What am I supposed to do here? I know I can differentiate the stuff inside the brackets using the Chain Rule and can then differentiate that bit by product rule and then apply the product rule again? Would that be a reasonable thing to do?

I have $y(t) = rcos(wt)i+rsin(wt)j+hwtk$

Where $w = (r^2+w^2)^{\frac{-1}{2}}$

So $y'(t) = -rsin(wt)i+rcos(wt)j+ ???$

Comment: I am confused by your question.  If you are differentiating with respect to $t$, then isn't every other variable in the expression construed to be a **constant**?

Comment: +1 : to the question, going from $(-2)$ to $(-1)$.  I am baffled why anyone would downvote this question.  The OP clearly showed very significant and conscientious work, and only went astray because of an analytical error.

Comment: OP - what is $h$? If a constant,  you are differentiating $h w t$ wrt to $t$ and what remains should be easy for you.

Comment: Also, you have that $w=(r^2+w^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$, are you certain of this relationship?

Comment: Is there no $x(t)$ ?

Comment: Please don't repost your question with different accounts. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4120819/what-is-the-derivative-of-x-times-y2x2-frac-12-times-t-times-w